# tvos Overriding pressesBegan

Tags: button, menu, tvos

I think I'm missing something pretty basic, but I can't get button presses to override properly.

I am trying to detect the menu button press, so I override `pressesBegan:` and test for the `UIPressTypeMenu`. The method catches the menu button press, and performs my code, but then immediately follows with an app exit anyway.

Here is my overridden method. Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong? Is there something else I need to override the automatic menu exit?  It's almost like there are two responders. Same deal with the left tap and right tap. They are recognized, my code fires, but then the focus changes anyway because I haven't completely handled the event.

I tried the code in the app's first view controller and the menu is overridden properly. Then, I set up a blank view and present that view as view number 2 and I cannot get the methods to override.

```
- (void)pressesBegan:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {

    for(UIPress *press in presses) {
        if(press.type == UIPressTypeMenu) {

            [(UIImageView *) [self.view viewWithTag:100] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

        }
        if(press.type == UIPressTypePlayPause) {
            // play and pause code
        }
    } 
}


-(void) pressesEnded:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {

    // 
    for(UIPress *press in presses) {
        if(press.type == UIPressTypeMenu) {
            // do ButtonA job
            NSLog(@"test");
        }
        if(press.type == UIPressTypePlayPause) {
            // do ButtonX job
        } else {


        }
    }

}

-(void) pressesChanged:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {

    // Works fine!
    for(UIPress *press in presses) {
        if(press.type == UIPressTypeMenu) {
            // do ButtonA job
        }
        if(press.type == UIPressTypePlayPause) {
            // do ButtonX job
        }
    }

}

-(void) pressesCancelled:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {

    // Works fine!
    for(UIPress *press in presses) {
        if(press.type == UIPressTypeMenu) {
            // do ButtonA job
            NSLog(@"cancelled");
        }
        if(press.type == UIPressTypePlayPause) {
            // do ButtonX job
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you resolve this? i'm also trying to capture the menu button.

Answer (score 2):

The app is exiting because you're allowing the `pressesEnded:withEvent:` message to get back up to the top of the responder chain. You should also override that method, and do *not* call `super` if you don't want the app to exit (be careful here, though: if the user can't use Menu to exit, they will be extremely frustrated with you)

The left and right arrows are triggering focus changes because those are handled with gesture recognizers, not with `pressesBegan` / `pressesEnded` methods, so it doesn't matter if your view overrides those.

The [Event Handling Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) has more details about how gesture recognizers and the `UIResponder` methods interact with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the potential help!  Actually i had also overriden pressesEnded, pressesChanged and pressesCancelled.  Sorry i should have put those into my question too.  I'm on not calling super in any of the methods.

Comment: And you're sure those methods are being called? Try setting a breakpoint in the debugger or adding some logging to be sure. Could you modify your question to include the code for those methods?

Comment: Actually pressesEnded doesn't seem to be getting called.  Although, on my first view pressesEnded is not getting called but the menu button is still being overridden.

Comment: actually, what i'm seeing is that pressesEnded is being called on a UIPressTypeLeft, Up, Right, Down, UIPressTypeSelect, and UIPressTypePlay, but NOT on the UIPressTypeMenu. Pressing the menu button will only call pressesBegan, and pressesCancelled. (not sure why pressesCancelled is called)           If i add in [self.view canBecomeFirstResponder] in the viewDidLoad, then I menu will still exit, but when i go right back into that view, the pressesEnded will get called then, but it's still not recognizing the menu button.

Comment: You're getting pressesCancelled because a gesture recognizer is firing: there must be a gesture recognizer somewhere in your app that's configured to listen for the Menu button. If you switch to using a gesture recognizer here (instead of pressesBegan, etc) then you should be able to recognize simultaneously. The Event Handling Guide I linked to explains how gestures can cancel touches and presses.

Comment: first off, i REALLY appreciate you spending the time to help me out.  What you're saying makes sense, and i had tried gestures when i first started putting the app together, but at this point everything is stripped out that i can see.  i'm only calling two views, the title page view, and a second view which i created for testing purposes that is completely blank except for the override methods.  i'm not sure where the gesture recognizer would even fire from.  i tried cleaning and reseting the simulator thinking that might help as Xcode is sometime finicky, but still getting the cancel.

Comment: Some built-in UIKit classes add gesture recognizers: UINavigationController and UITabBarController both do, for instance. So that's where the gesture could be coming from. But if your gesture is attached to a view lower down in the view hierarchy (in other words, "closer" to the focused view) then your gesture will take precedence.

Comment: it continues to baffle me.  Like you suggested, I was able to override the menu by using a gesture. But when i try to register the UIPressTypeLeftArrow, it doesn't matter if i use gestures, or pressesEnded, the left arrow changes the focus.  my methods are being called with a gesture, or when i use presses, pressesEnded is called.  BUT the focus changes as well.  If i try to set a BOOL to set shouldUpdateFocusInContext to return No, it will change focus one time, and then will stop focussing with the left tap. but when i move the focus again with pan, and hit UIPressLeft, focus changes again.

Comment: I noted the same problem. I have UINavigationController and I wanted to make some custom behaviour on MENU button press on the last UIViewController. Although all press methods are overwritten only pressesBegin and pressesCancelled are called and my UIViewController is poped like in standard behaviour which I want to avoid. I also tried to create subclass for UINavigationController and override presses methods to not call super but it also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget this on you gameScene:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
}
```